# Migrate CSV source serial

Tags: commerce, migrations

I am using migrate to import Commerce Products from a CSV file. The CSV file doesn't have its own serial so I am using csvrownum but that obviously won't work if there are already products -- I will be migrating constantly from the CSV files and so I need a real serial. So the big question is, how do I tell Migrate to generate its own serial? `prepareRow` feels too late because it seems I need to supply MigrateSQLMap a key field.

Here's a rough version of the constructor of the class:

```
public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->description = t('Test CSV');

  $columns = array(
    array('product_name', 'title'),
    array('url', 'url'),
    array('price', 'price'),
  );

  $this->source = new MigrateSourceCSV('/tmp/test.csv', $columns, array('header_rows' => 1));

  $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationCommerceProduct('commerce_product', 'product');

  $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
    array(
      'csvrownum' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => true,
      ),
    ),
    MigrateDestinationCommerceProduct::getKeySchema('commerce_product')
  );

  $this->addFieldMapping('product_id', 'csvrownum');
  $this->addFieldMapping('title', 'title');
  $this->addFieldMapping('field_url', 'url');
  $this->addFieldMapping('commerce_price', 'price');
}
```

Comment: Are you rolling back your migrations while testing ? If not it could lead to duplicate entries issues. It could be done with `drush mr YourClassName`. Using `csvrownum` as a key field shouldn't be a problem as far as it is unique ...

Comment: yeah, and a lot of progress happened when i just blew away the database.

Comment: AFAIK you can use `prepareRow` as far as you provide the field as the fourth parameter in your [constructor](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21migrate%21plugins%21sources%21csv.inc/function/MigrateSourceCSV%3A%3A__construct/7).

Comment: As the answer shows, prepareRow is too late, you want prepareKey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meanwhile I got this figured out. The second argument of `MigrateSQLMap` is a field => schema array and you can fill in those fields in `function prepareKey($source_key, $row)` as necessary, say

```
function prepareKey($source_key, $row) {
  $row->vendor_id = $this->vendorId;
  return parent::prepareKey($source_key, $row);
}
```

**Note**: `prepareRow` is too late, you want `prepareKey`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to map the `product_id` explicitly. You should be able to just drop this line:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('product_id', 'csvrownum');
```

On the other hand, you are going to need a SKU, and relying on `csvnumrow` as the external ID means that you cannot ever remove any product from the CSV, just add some more at the end... I would highly recommend finding a reliable external ID.